# Unable to load dynamic data into ui-grid dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, scope, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) with [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) (and MySQL at backend) for a project. I got a table which gets its data from MySQL database. Its rows (or cells) are editable (as mentioned in this [example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable) on ui-grid website). One column of the table has dropdown. Dropdown is working perfectly with hard coded data as described in that example. I want to populate it from database but it shows empty dropdown list everytime I tried.

Fetching of data from database is done by service which is injected into the controller with intention to run the code that gets data from database (i.e. $http.get('/some/route')) so that we have all the data for table rows and dropdown list in hand before or at the time of page loading.

But the variable (sitesD) that gets data for dropdown when printed, shows it is undefined.

Here is the controller:

```
angular.module('WorkersCtrl', []).controller('WorkersController', function($scope, $http, serverData) {

$scope.gridOptions = {enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1};

/* getting rows from databse by using "serverData" custom service */
serverData.getData().then(function(response) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data[0];
        $scope.sitesData = response.data[1];
});
var sitesD = $scope.sitesData;
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { field: 'first_name', width:150, enableCellEdit: true},
    { field: 'last_name', width:150},
    { field: 'father_first_name', width:150},
    { field: 'father_last_name', width:150},
    { field: 'mother_first_name', width:150},
    { field: 'mother_last_name', width:150},
    { field: 'sex', width:50, editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
        editDropdownValueLabel: 'gender', editDropdownOptionsArray: [
          { id: 'M', gender: 'Male' },
          { id: 'F', gender: 'Female' }]},
    { field: 'address', width:250},
    { field: 'phone', width:100, type: 'number'},
    { field: 'date_of_birth', width:150, type: 'date', cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd"'},
    { field: 'post_code', displayName: 'Post', width:50},
    { field: 'joining_date', width:150, type: 'date', cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd"'},
    { field: 'rate', width:50, type: 'number'},
    { field: 'site_name', width:150, editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
    editDropdownIdLabel:'site_id', editDropdownValueLabel: 'site_name', editDropdownOptionsArray: sitesD },
];
alert(sitesD); //checking the variable value: it shows undefined.

$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
};

$scope.addData = function() {
    $scope.gridOptions.data.push({
        'first_name': '',
        'last_name': '',
        'father_first_name': '',
        'father_last_name': '',
        'mother_first_name': '',
        'mother_last_name': '',
        'sex': '',
        'address': '',
        'phone': '',
        'date_of_birth': '',
        'post_code': '',
        'joining_date': '',
        'rate': '',
        'site_name': ''
    });
};
});
```

Code of service is following:

```
angular.module('GeekService', []).factory('serverData', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('/workers')
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is the screenshot of page when `alert(sitesD);` runs:
[image]

What I understand is variable gets value after the page loads and so the `editDropdownOptionsArray` gets no value for dropdown.

All these are assumptions I made while looking for solution but haven't sceeded yet. Please help me. I feel I am even didn't understand where's the problem.

Feel free to ask further information if needed.

PS: While writing the question I found there is version incompatibility between my Angular and ui-grid. ui-grid 3.x is compatible with Angular's 1.4.x but I'm using ui-grid 3.x with Angular 1.5.5. Is it can be the reason?

EDIT: Here is the screenshot, showing how the dropdown looks:
[image]

Comment: after you get the data with `$http` use `$scope.apply();`

Comment: I tried it as following:
`serverData.getData().then(function(response) {                    
        $scope.$apply(function(){                                     
            $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data[0];               
            $scope.sitesData = response.data[1];                      
        });                                                           
    }); `

It throws this error: Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress

Answer (score 3):

Harmanpreet,

Since you are bringing in dynamic content asynchronously I would recommend looking at the ui-grid "editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath" functionality instead of "editDropdownOptionsArray" as that functionality appears to be meant for static values as you are discovering now.  There is information on this on the UI-grid API site: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.edit.api:ColumnDef

If the data is a static list and won't be changing or dependent then maybe the code below would work as well, thanks for reaching out:

```
serverData.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data[0];
    $scope.sitesData = response.data[1];

    // You may have to shape data in a method before doing the next line
    // ex: var sitesArray = shapeSitesData();

    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[13].editDropdownOptionsArray = $scope.sitesData;
});
```

Since Stackoverflow doesn't respect new people's opinions I cannot comment on your thread with transistor.  Hopefully you see this as I believe it will help.  The issue you are encountering could also be due to the fact that ui-grid doesn't do a great job of mapping ids and values. You should try my variant (which i believe improves upon @mltroutt's solution).

```
angular.module('app')
     .controller('yourctrl', yourFunction)
     .filter('griddropdown', function () {
    return function (input, context) {
        var fieldLevel = (context.editDropdownOptionsArray == undefined) ? context.col.colDef : context;
        var map = fieldLevel.editDropdownOptionsArray;
        var idField = fieldLevel.editDropdownIdLabel;
        var valueField = fieldLevel.editDropdownValueLabel;
        var initial = context.row.entity[context.col.field];
        if (typeof map !== "undefined") {
            for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
                if (map[i][idField] == input) {
                    return map[i][valueField];
                }
            }
        }
        else if (initial) {
            return initial;
        }
        return input;
    };
```

Then add this to your coldef

```
cellFilter: 'griddropdown:this'
```

Comment: However, the original problem was solved by @ transistor1's suggestions, but this code block saved me hours in figuring out how to map id and corresponding value in the dropdown. Your code worked so perfectly that I just copy-pasted and saved and it worked. Thanks a lot @Brendon for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timing issue.  At the point where you're calling `alert(sitesD)`, your data hasn't loaded yet.  Angular promises are asynchronous, which is what the `then` statement is for.

If you move your alert inside the `then`, your dropdown data should appear:

```
serverData.getData().then(function(response) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data[0];
        $scope.sitesData = response.data[1];
        alert($scope.sitesData);
});
```

If it's still undefined, either response.data[1] doesn't contain your data, or you've got a problem with your server-side logic.

If your data does appear correctly in the `then` alert, next try changing `editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.sitesData`

**Edit:** in my solution, I use an angular-resource instead of $http, and it works as described above.  You may want to try this, though I'd expect it to work the way you've coded it with $http as well.

```
angular.module('siteDataService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('siteData', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/workers', {}, {
    query: { method:'GET', isArray: true }
  }
});
```

Make sure you include `angular-resource.js` in your HTML, and take a dependency on `siteDataService` in your application, and add `siteData` in your controller.

To run the query, you'd use `$scope.serverResponse = siteData.query();` in the body of your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply transistor1. I tried that thing so many times before posting the question here. Yes, the alert inside the `then` shows data which means $scope.sitesData actually contains data, but the dropdown is still empty.

Comment: Did you try changing  `editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.sitesData` ?

Comment: Yes I did. Nothing changed.

Comment: Please post the JSON response you get back in `$scope.sitesData`.

Comment: Here it is: 

[{"site_id":2,"site_name":"Honda Showroom"},{"site_id":3,"site_name":"Toyota Showroom"},{"site_id":4,"site_name":"undefined"},{"site_id":5,"site_name":"Red Mango"},{"site_id":6,"site_name":"Maharaja Grand"},{"site_id":8,"site_name":"Westend Mall"},{"site_id":9,"site_name":"Haveli"},{"site_id":10,"site_name":"Oswal Mills"},{"site_id":11,"site_name":"GNE College"},{"site_id":12,"site_name":"Grand Mall"},{"site_id":13,"site_name":"McDonalds"},{"site_id":14,"site_name":"Civil Hospital"},{"site_id":15,"site_name":"Haveli"}]

Comment: This looks fine (I'd add it to your question so other people can see it as well) Can you add a screenshot of what is appearing when you open the dropdown?  I'm wondering if it's showing blank lines where data should be, or if it is showing no data at all.  Also I assume that your grid data is populating correctly, right?

Comment: Screenshot added. Dropdown has no blank lines. Yes, the grid data (i.e. other columns of table) are getting data in a way they should be.

Comment: If you've made the changes I suggested, the only differences that I can still spot between your example, and what I'm currently using in production (Angular 1.5, ui-grid 3.x) is that (1) I'm using an angular-resource instead of raw $http, and (2) my server-side service returns only a single data item per call -- that is to say, you'd call the `/worker/sitedata` URL to get the site data, and `/worker/griddata` separately to populate your grid.  I edited my answer to provide info on how to use an angular resource.

Comment: Your both suggestions just worked! Dropdown is working now. A big thank you for your help. :)